# process ffmpeg command on nodejs with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm programming a tool for convert MP4 to HLS with nodejs , I'm trying to use fluent-ffmpeg to convert it , but I have some error at giving "outputOptions" .

My code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

// open input stream
var infs = new ffmpeg

infs.addInput('./data/test3.mp4').outputOptions([
    '-map 0:0',
    '-map 0:1',
    '-map 0:0',
    '-map 0:1',
    '-s:v:0 2160x3840',
    '-c:v:0 libx264',
    '-b:v:0 2000k',
    '-s:v:1 960x540',
    '-c:v:1 libx264',
    '-b:v:1 365k',
    '-var_stream_map', '"v:0,a:0', 'v:1,a:1"',
    '-master_pl_name master.m3u8',
    '-f hls',
    '-hls_time 1',
    '-hls_list_size 0',
    '-hls_segment_filename', '"v%v/fileSequence%d.ts"'
]).output('./data/v%v/prog_index.m3u8')
    .on('start', function (commandLine) {
        console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
    })
    .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message, err, stderr);
    })
    .on('progress', function (progress) {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
    })
    .on('end', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('Finished processing!' /*, err, stdout, stderr*/)
    })
    .run()
```

the error i get is

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: v:1,a:1": Invalid argument
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'v:1,a:1"'
```

i have try to print out the command that fluent-ffmpeg spawned and i get

```
fmpeg -i ./data/test3.mp4 -y -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -s:v:0 2160x3840 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 2000k -s:v:1 960x540 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 365k -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "v%v/fileSequence%d.ts" ./data/v%v/prog_index.m3u8
```

I paste this command in terminal and I can success convert the mp4 to hls.

what should I do at my code to let it success convert?

fluent-ffmpeg version : 2.1.2

ffmpeg version : 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: As per this fluent-ffmpeg issue [comment](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/502#issuecomment-196709174), quote the vsm arg in single quotes, and use double quotes for the outer quotes.

---

The var_stream_map arg should be one string i.e.

```
'"v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1"',
```

Comment: i alse tried this too   ```'-var_stream_map', '"v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1"',
    '-master_pl_name master.m3u8'   
``` but i still get this error  
```Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: v:1,a:1": Invalid argument```

Comment: sorry, I'm confuse that "quote the vsm arg in single quotes, and use double quotes for the outer quotes." . It's seem like I have to give the option like this 
```['-var_stream_map', '"v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1"']```
but it still not correct.

Comment: Like this:     `"-var_stream_map", "'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1'"`

Comment: not work .  The  [Error](https://imgur.com/7jh6AYf)  I get still same. I think it always get the space between   a:0  v:1  and it parse v:1 to be the next command not param

Comment: Don't pass it as an array. See last example at https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#outputoptionsoption-add-custom-output-options

Comment: it works. I remove array and I change param like this 
```"-var_stream_map", 'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1'
```  
 thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#outputoptionsoption-add-custom-output-options) Documentation. It can be resolved using outputOptions(option...) added before the output() function.

so, final solution is look like..

```
    infs.addInput('./data/test3.mp4').outputOptions([
    '-map 0:v', '-map 0:a', '-map 0:v','-map 0:a',
    '-s:v:0 2160x3840',
    '-c:v:0 libx264',
    '-b:v:0 2000k',
    '-s:v:1 960x540',
    '-c:v:1 libx264',
    '-b:v:1 365k',
    '-master_pl_name master.m3u8',
    '-f hls',
    '-hls_time 1',
    '-hls_list_size 0',
    '-hls_segment_filename', '"v%v/fileSequence%d.ts"'])
.outputOption('-var_stream_map', 'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1')
.output('./data/v%v/prog_index.m3u8')
    .on('start', function (commandLine) {
        console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
    })
    .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message, err, stderr);
    })
    .on('progress', function (progress) {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
    })
    .on('end', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('Finished processing!' /*, err, stdout, stderr*/)
    })
    .run()
```